# nvD3 Lineplusbar chart tool tip shows incorrect date (12/31/1969)

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I am new to nvD3 and trying to implement Lineplusbar chart in NVD3. I have used the code from nvd3 website as is. however the tooltips shows incorrect dates

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="./nvd3//build/nv.d3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.2/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="./nvd3/build/nv.d3.js"></script>


        <style>

        #chart svg {
        height: 400px;
        }

        </style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="chart">
    <svg></svg>
</div>

    <script>

    var data = [
  {
    "key" : "Quantity",
    "bar": true,
    "values" : [ [ 1136005200000 , 1271000.0] , [ 1138683600000 , 1271000.0] , [ 1141102800000 , 1271000.0] , [ 1143781200000 , 0] , [ 1146369600000 , 0] , [ 1149048000000 , 0] , [ 1151640000000 , 0] , [ 1154318400000 , 0] , [ 1156996800000 , 0] , [ 1159588800000 , 3899486.0] , [ 1162270800000 , 3899486.0] , [ 1164862800000 , 3899486.0] , [ 1167541200000 , 3564700.0] , [ 1170219600000 , 3564700.0] , [ 1172638800000 , 3564700.0] , [ 1175313600000 , 2648493.0] , [ 1177905600000 , 2648493.0] , [ 1180584000000 , 2648493.0] , [ 1183176000000 , 2522993.0] , [ 1185854400000 , 2522993.0] , [ 1188532800000 , 2522993.0] , [ 1191124800000 , 2906501.0] , [ 1193803200000 , 2906501.0] , [ 1196398800000 , 2906501.0] , [ 1199077200000 , 2206761.0] , [ 1201755600000 , 2206761.0] , [ 1204261200000 , 2206761.0] , [ 1206936000000 , 2287726.0] , [ 1209528000000 , 2287726.0] , [ 1212206400000 , 2287726.0] , [ 1214798400000 , 2732646.0] , [ 1217476800000 , 2732646.0] , [ 1220155200000 , 2732646.0] , [ 1222747200000 , 2599196.0] , [ 1225425600000 , 2599196.0] , [ 1228021200000 , 2599196.0] , [ 1230699600000 , 1924387.0] , [ 1233378000000 , 1924387.0] , [ 1235797200000 , 1924387.0] , [ 1238472000000 , 1756311.0] , [ 1241064000000 , 1756311.0] , [ 1243742400000 , 1756311.0] , [ 1246334400000 , 1743470.0] , [ 1249012800000 , 1743470.0] , [ 1251691200000 , 1743470.0] , [ 1254283200000 , 1519010.0] , [ 1256961600000 , 1519010.0] , [ 1259557200000 , 1519010.0] , [ 1262235600000 , 1591444.0] , [ 1264914000000 , 1591444.0] , [ 1267333200000 , 1591444.0] , [ 1270008000000 , 1543784.0] , [ 1272600000000 , 1543784.0] , [ 1275278400000 , 1543784.0] , [ 1277870400000 , 1309915.0] , [ 1280548800000 , 1309915.0] , [ 1283227200000 , 1309915.0] , [ 1285819200000 , 1331875.0] , [ 1288497600000 , 1331875.0] , [ 1291093200000 , 1331875.0] , [ 1293771600000 , 1331875.0] , [ 1296450000000 , 1154695.0] , [ 1298869200000 , 1154695.0] , [ 1301544000000 , 1194025.0] , [ 1304136000000 , 1194025.0] , [ 1306814400000 , 1194025.0] , [ 1309406400000 , 1194025.0] , [ 1312084800000 , 1194025.0] , [ 1314763200000 , 1244525.0] , [ 1317355200000 , 475000.0] , [ 1320033600000 , 475000.0] , [ 1322629200000 , 475000.0] , [ 1325307600000 , 690033.0] , [ 1327986000000 , 690033.0] , [ 1330491600000 , 690033.0] , [ 1333166400000 , 514733.0] , [ 1335758400000 , 514733.0]]
  },
  {
    "key" : "Price",
    "values" : [ [ 1136005200000 , 71.89] , [ 1138683600000 , 75.51] , [ 1141102800000 , 68.49] , [ 1143781200000 , 62.72] , [ 1146369600000 , 70.39] , [ 1149048000000 , 59.77] , [ 1151640000000 , 57.27] , [ 1154318400000 , 67.96] , [ 1156996800000 , 67.85] , [ 1159588800000 , 76.98] , [ 1162270800000 , 81.08] , [ 1164862800000 , 91.66] , [ 1167541200000 , 84.84] , [ 1170219600000 , 85.73] , [ 1172638800000 , 84.61] , [ 1175313600000 , 92.91] , [ 1177905600000 , 99.8] , [ 1180584000000 , 121.191] , [ 1183176000000 , 122.04] , [ 1185854400000 , 131.76] , [ 1188532800000 , 138.48] , [ 1191124800000 , 153.47] , [ 1193803200000 , 189.95] , [ 1196398800000 , 182.22] , [ 1199077200000 , 198.08] , [ 1201755600000 , 135.36] , [ 1204261200000 , 125.02] , [ 1206936000000 , 143.5] , [ 1209528000000 , 173.95] , [ 1212206400000 , 188.75] , [ 1214798400000 , 167.44] , [ 1217476800000 , 158.95] , [ 1220155200000 , 169.53] , [ 1222747200000 , 113.66] , [ 1225425600000 , 107.59] , [ 1228021200000 , 92.67] , [ 1230699600000 , 85.35] , [ 1233378000000 , 90.13] , [ 1235797200000 , 89.31] , [ 1238472000000 , 105.12] , [ 1241064000000 , 125.83] , [ 1243742400000 , 135.81] , [ 1246334400000 , 142.43] , [ 1249012800000 , 163.39] , [ 1251691200000 , 168.21] , [ 1254283200000 , 185.35] , [ 1256961600000 , 188.5] , [ 1259557200000 , 199.91] , [ 1262235600000 , 210.732] , [ 1264914000000 , 192.063] , [ 1267333200000 , 204.62] , [ 1270008000000 , 235.0] , [ 1272600000000 , 261.09] , [ 1275278400000 , 256.88] , [ 1277870400000 , 251.53] , [ 1280548800000 , 257.25] , [ 1283227200000 , 243.1] , [ 1285819200000 , 283.75] , [ 1288497600000 , 300.98] , [ 1291093200000 , 311.15] , [ 1293771600000 , 322.56] , [ 1296450000000 , 339.32] , [ 1298869200000 , 353.21] , [ 1301544000000 , 348.5075] , [ 1304136000000 , 350.13] , [ 1306814400000 , 347.83] , [ 1309406400000 , 335.67] , [ 1312084800000 , 390.48] , [ 1314763200000 , 384.83] , [ 1317355200000 , 381.32] , [ 1320033600000 , 404.78] , [ 1322629200000 , 382.2] , [ 1325307600000 , 405.0] , [ 1327986000000 , 456.48] , [ 1330491600000 , 542.44] , [ 1333166400000 , 599.55] , [ 1335758400000 , 583.98]]
  }
]



nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.linePlusBarChart()
      .margin({top: 30, right: 60, bottom: 50, left: 70})
      .x(function(d,i) { return i })
      .y(function(d) { return d[1] })
      .color(d3.scale.category10().range())
     // .height(500)
      ;

    chart.xAxis
      .showMaxMin(true)
      .tickFormat(function(d) {

        var dx = data[0].values[d] && data[0].values[d][0] || 0;
                console.log("dx = " + dx);

        return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(dx))
      });

    chart.y1Axis
      .tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));

    chart.y2Axis
      .tickFormat(function(d) { return '$' + d3.format(',f')(d) });

    chart.bars.forceY([0]);

    d3.select('#chart svg')
      .datum(data)
      .transition().duration(500)
      .call(chart)
      ;

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

    return chart;
});


</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Looks like the issue is with the xAxis as no matter what dx get the value 0

```
    chart.xAxis
  .showMaxMin(true)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {

    var dx = data[0].values[d] && data[0].values[d][0] || 0;
    return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(dx))
  });
```

Can can someone help fix this issue please.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind! I figured out the answer. I think the issue was with the way the date was being parsed.

The date needs to be parsed in to milliseconds

```
Date.parse( d.log_day )
```